SQLite3 Update function does not update when used in another function
I have an update function for my database. If I run the function itself, it immediately updates the database, when the function is executed. I have another function where I use it and the database does not immediately update after the function is executed, but rather when the program is finished.
Here is my update_athlete:
def update_athlete(id, first_name="", last_name="", age="", acceleration="", endurance="", form="", mental="", speed="", stamina="", start="", place="", last_race_time="", last_race_type="", fastest_100m="", fastest_200m="", fastest_400m="", races_ran=""):
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect(r"track.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        
        #Check if the athlete with the given id exists
        cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM Athletes WHERE id=?", (id,))
        existing_id = cursor.fetchone()
        
        if existing_id:
            #Build the SET clause based on provided parameters
            params = []
            set_clause_parts = []
            for attr, value in [("first_name", first_name), ("last_name", last_name), ("age", age), ("acceleration", acceleration), ("endurance", endurance), ("form", form), ("mental", mental), ("speed", speed), ("stamina", stamina), ("start", start), ("place", place), ("last_race_time", last_race_time), ("last_race_type", last_race_type), ("fastest_100m", fastest_100m), ("fastest_200m", fastest_200m), ("fastest_400m", fastest_400m), ("races_ran", races_ran)]:
                if value != "":
                    set_clause_parts.append(f"{attr}=?")
                    params.append(value)
            set_clause = ", ".join(set_clause_parts)
            
            #Add the id parameter to the end
            params.append(id)
            sql_statement = f"UPDATE Athletes SET {set_clause} WHERE id=?"
            
            #Execute the SQL statement with the provided values
            cursor.execute(sql_statement, params)
            connection.commit()
        else:
            print(f"Athlete with id {id} not found.")

    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        if connection:
            connection.close()

My Race function which uses the update_athlete function:
def one_hundred_meters_race(runners):
        
        runners_time = []
        winning_time = 15.00
        winner = None

        #Simulate race and find winner
        for runner in runners:
            runner_time = float(f"{one_hundred_meters(runner):.2f}")
            runners_time.append(runner_time)

            if runner_time < winning_time:
                winning_time = runner_time
                winner = f"{runner.first_name} {runner.last_name}"
        
        #Update the database records
        for runner, time in zip(runners, runners_time):
            backend.update_athlete(runner.id, last_race_time=time, last_race_type="100m")

            if time < runner.fastest_100m:
                backend.update_athlete(runner.id, fastest_100m=time)

            backend.update_athlete(runner.id, stamina=(runner.stamina-10))
            backend.update_athlete(runner.id, races_ran=(runner.races_ran+1))
        
        #Print the race results
        print(f"100m: {len(runners)} runners")
        print("------------------------------")
        for i, runner in enumerate(runners):
            print(f"Lane {i+1}: {runner.first_name} {runner.last_name} ran {runners_time[i]}. OVR: {runner.overall_100m}")

        print(f"The winner is {winner} with a time of {winning_time}")

        #Sort the race results
        sort_race(runners_time, runners)

If I run:
one_hundred_meters_race(runners)
one_hundred_meters_race(runners)

The athlete is only updated with the information of the last race. The runners should have their stamina decreased by 20 and their race_ran increased by 2. Instead their stamina is decreased by 10 and their race_ran is increased by 1.
If I run:
backend.update_athlete(94, stamina=(backend.get_athlete(94).stamina+5))
backend.update_athlete(94, stamina=(backend.get_athlete(94).stamina+5))

The athlete's stamina will increase by 10.
I am new to SQL and Python. I don't understand why both changes reflect when I run update_athlete alone, but not when I run one_hundred_meters_race. I've added logging functions and it says the update is sucessful, but when I print out the athlete the information it does not look updated. Once the program is finished running, the database does reflect updates, but only from the latest one_hundred_meters_race. There are no updates from the other one_hundred_meters_race functions called.
I've added logging functions to see if the database is being updated and when. I added exceptions to print errors. I tried testing the update_athletes function alone. The update functions works when ran alone and it seems to update the database properly according to logs. But changes are not displayed when calling one_hundred_meters_race multiple times in a row. Changes are only displayed after the entire program is finished executed. Also only changes for the last one_hundred_meters_race are made.
I expect the database to reflect updates after each one_hundred_meters_race.
